# Symfony's framework.ide config for PhpStorm and Vagrant

Tags: symfony, vagrant, phpstorm

How do I set up [`framework.ide` config value](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ide) so that it properly links to files in PhpStorm, when the code is run from Vagrant?

I've tried `phpstorm://open?file=%%f&line=%%l`

but it gives me Vagrant paths, like:
`phpstorm://open?file=/vagrant/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php&line=27`

while I should be getting host paths, like:
`phpstorm://open?file=/Volumes/my_project_volume/project_name/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php&line=27`

I guess the solution would be to somehow configure path mapping, either in Symfony or in PhpStorm.

Comment: what do you want to do finally please ?

Comment: > I should be getting host paths, like: phpstorm://open?file=/Volumes/my_project_volume/project_name/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php&line=27

Answer (score 3):

Regarding symfony's official documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ide

you can use (from symfony 3.2) something like this:

```
ide: 'phpstorm://open?file=%%f&line=%%l&/path/on/vagrant>/your/local/path/'
```

Comment: Cool, unfortunately I have 2.8.x

Comment: So you should definitely upgrade. From 2.8 it's painless :)

Answer (score 1):

For a project relative directory:

```
framework:
    ide: 'phpstorm://open?url=file://%%f&line=%%l&/path/in/server>%kernel.project_dir%'
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with Docker and with Mac, and your project is hosted in your user folder, the configuration has to slightly get changed as well.

```yaml
framework:
    ide: 'phpstorm://open?file=%%f&line=%%l&/app/>/Users/your-username/PhpstormProjects/your-project-folder/'
```

Please note that

- `/app/` is the path inside the Docker container,
- using `~/PhpstormProjects` as alias to the home directory is something PHPStorm does not seem to support